# How can change the shell name in docker container

Tags: linux, docker

While I am running the docker container I am using rocker. The command is

```
rocker --x11 --home --user-preserve-home --user --privileged --name universe --volume /dev/input:/dev/input:ro --volume /run/udev:/run/udev:ro --volume /dev:/dev --network host  --
```

However the name of shell in the container is same as host terminal so I can not understand which is container terminal which is not.

I want to ask that is there any way to change the name in shell on container?

I couldn't any way to change it.

Comment: What is "name of a shell"? You mean the text in shell prompt printed before each command is typed in? $PS1? or $0, called sometimes command name?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "blabla@archlinux:~$" I want to change this name for example like ""docker_blabla@archlinux:~$" but I don't want to change the parameters in rocker commands like --user and --network host